# How to set single verse numbering with poetry package?

Tags: counters, line-numbering, poetry

I am using the **poetry package**, in memoir with LuaLatex.
The poem that brings me here is a fragment, so my goal is that the first line has the numbering [17], and then from line 20 the numbering is established in multiples of 5.

With poetry I managed to set the numbering every 5 lines, but I can't get the first one to carry the number 17 or not start from 1. Thank you in advance.

Here I provide a minimal working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{poetry}

\begin{document}


\chapter*{Example}

\setcounter{poemindentevery}{0}
\setlength{\poemindent}{0in}
\setlength{\poemhangindent}{0in}
\poemlinenumstrue
\setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}

\begin{poem}
¿Genio? En este momento\\
cien mil cerebros se creen en sueños genios como yo\\
y la historia no recordará, ¿quién sabe?, ni uno,\\
y sólo habrá un muladar para tantas futuras conquistas.\\
No, no creo en mí.\\
¡En tantos manicomios hay tantos locos con tantas certezas!\\
Yo, que no tengo ninguna ¿puedo estar en lo cierto?\\
No, en mí no creo.\\
¿En cuántas buhardillas y no-buhardillas del mundo\\
genios-para-sí-mismos a esta hora están soñando?\\
¿Cuántas aspiraciones altas y nobles y lúcidas\\
(sí, de veras altas y nobles y lúcidas)\\
quizá realizables,\\
no verán nunca la luz del sol real ni llegarán a oídos de la gente?\\
El mundo es para los que nacieron para conquistarlo\\
no para los que sueñan que pueden conquistarlo, aunque tengan razón.\\-
\end{poem}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please accept David's answer if it works for you. Thanks. (We work hard for every point!)

Answer (score 3):

The `memoir` class has its own code for typesetting poetry so in general you don't need to use the `poetry` package. The code below, a modification of your MWE, gives the same result as the answer from @DavidCarlisle.

```
% poetryprob.tex  SE 583257

\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{poetry}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Example}

\begin{comment}

\setcounter{poemindentevery}{0}
\setlength{\poemindent}{0in}
\setlength{\poemhangindent}{0in}
\poemlinenumstrue
\setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}

\begin{poem}\poemlineno=17
¿Genio? En este momento\\
cien mil cerebros se creen en sueños genios como yo\\
y la historia no recordará, ¿quién sabe?, ni uno,\\
y sólo habrá un muladar para tantas futuras conquistas.\\
No, no creo en mí.\\
¡En tantos manicomios hay tantos locos con tantas certezas!\\
Yo, que no tengo ninguna ¿puedo estar en lo cierto?\\
No, en mí no creo.\\
¿En cuántas buhardillas y no-buhardillas del mundo\\
genios-para-sí-mismos a esta hora están soñando?\\
¿Cuántas aspiraciones altas y nobles y lúcidas\\
(sí, de veras altas y nobles y lúcidas)\\
quizá realizables,\\
no verán nunca la luz del sol real ni llegarán a oídos de la gente?\\
El mundo es para los que nacieron para conquistarlo\\
no para los que sueñan que pueden conquistarlo, aunque tengan razón.\\-
\end{poem}
\clearpage
\end{comment}

% HERE FOLLOWS THE `memoir` CODE

\setlength{\vleftmargin}{0pt}  % \setcounter{poemindentevery}{0}
% \setlength{\poemindent}{0in}
% \setlength{\poemhangindent}{0in}
%\poemlinenumstrue
\linenumberfrequency{5} %\setcounter{poemlinenumsevery}{5}

\verselinenumbersleft % line numbers normally set right
\setlength{\vrightskip}{2em} % space for line numbers, normally 1em
%\begin{poem}\poemlineno=17
\begin{verse} \setverselinenums{17}{21} % first line number, first printed number
¿Genio? En este momento\\
cien mil cerebros se creen en sueños genios como yo\\
y la historia no recordará, ¿quién sabe?, ni uno,\\
y sólo habrá un muladar para tantas futuras conquistas.\\
No, no creo en mí.\\
¡En tantos manicomios hay tantos locos con tantas certezas!\\
Yo, que no tengo ninguna ¿puedo estar en lo cierto?\\
No, en mí no creo.\\
¿En cuántas buhardillas y no-buhardillas del mundo\\
genios-para-sí-mismos a esta hora están soñando?\\
¿Cuántas aspiraciones altas y nobles y lúcidas\\
(sí, de veras altas y nobles y lúcidas)\\
quizá realizables,\\
no verán nunca la luz del sol real ni llegarán a oídos de la gente?\\
El mundo es para los que nacieron para conquistarlo\\
no para los que sueñan que pueden conquistarlo, aunque tengan razón. % \\-
%\end{poem}
\end{verse}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: The memoir class option worked perfectly, and allowed me to choose the 20, 25, 30, etc. series instead of the 21, 26, 31, etc. series. 
For some reason the \poemlineno=17 option did not work in accurately determining each line. I forgot to include in my MWE that the first line of my poem was preceded by \textgreek[variant=ancient], which perhaps altered the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the counter at the start

```
\begin{poem}\poemlineno=17
```

Produces

[image]